# Filter records when selecting records from SQL table

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-express

My problem is the following: I'd like to get some records from a SQL Server table and display them on textboxes in my form.

What I want now is to `SELECT` these records but filter them with a `WHERE` condition.

Here's where I connect to the databases I'm using:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    try
    {
        objConnect = new DatabaseConnection();
        conString = Properties.Settings.Default.barcodeConnectionString;

        objConnect.connection_string = conString;
        objConnect.Sql = Properties.Settings.Default.SQL;

        ds = objConnect.GetConnection;
        MaxRows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;              
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
    }

    try
    {
        objConnect = new DatabaseConnection();
        conString = Properties.Settings.Default.barcodeConnectionString;

        objConnect.connection_string = conString;
        objConnect.Sql = Properties.Settings.Default.SQL2;

        ds2 = objConnect.GetConnection;
        MaxRows2 = ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count; 
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
    }
```

Here's where I grab records:

```
private void NavigateRecords()
{
    dRow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[inc];                       

    if (textBox1.Text == dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString())
    {
        textBox2.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
        textBox3.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(9).ToString();
    }
}

private void NavigateRecordz()
{
    dRow2 = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[inc2];

    if (textBox1.Text == dRow2.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString())
    {
        textBox4.Text = dRow2.ItemArray.GetValue(10).ToString();
        textBox5.Text = dRow2.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
    }
}
```

In the tab explore solutions, under Properties --> Settings I got these 2 properties with the following value:

```
SELECT * FROM DAT_SCOMPART
```

and like this it's working;

If I try to use

```
SELECT * 
FROM DAT_SCOMPART 
WHERE SCO_UDC > 99999
```

(that's the filter I need) it doesn't return the records anymore.

Any idea on how I could filter the records?

The code is corrected and with this two button click events is working:

```
private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (inc < MaxRows -1)
            {
                inc++;                
                NavigateRecords();                
                btnRefresh.PerformClick();
            }
            else
            {                
                inc = 0;                                
                textBox2.Focus();
            }                       

        }

            private void btnRefresh2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (inc2 < MaxRows2 - 1)
            {
                inc2++;
                NavigateRecordz();
                btnRefresh2.PerformClick();
            }
            else
            {
                inc2 = -1;
                textBox2.Focus();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure there are records matching your criterias and  `SCO_UDC` is of type int?

Comment: Is `SCO_UDC` of type integer? Try putting ` around your table and column names (like `SCO_UDC`), although I don't believe this is the reason it fails.

Comment: Any Exception? What's SCO_UDC column type?

Comment: SCO_UDC is actually decimal (15,0)

Comment: Do you get an error message? Either it does not find any records because there aren't any, or there must be an error message!

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post the error as well! Eccezione non gestita di tipo 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' in System.Data.dll

Ulteriori informazioni: Nessuna riga alla posizione 5.

Comment: IndexOutOfRange means that the index you are using is larger than the amount of elements in your array/list. So check whether `Tables`, `Rows` or your `ItemArray` really contain as many elements as your indices want. This should fix your issue (which is not sql-related, as far as I can see). Check the size of your lists before trying to access them.

Comment: I thought this was enough to avoid IndexOutOfRange: "private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (inc != MaxRows - 1 && inc2 != MaxRows2 - 1)
            {
                inc++;
                inc2++;
                NavigateRecords();
                NavigateRecordz();
                btnRefresh.PerformClick();
            }
            else
            {                
                inc = 0;
                inc2 = 0;                
                textBox2.Focus();
            }                       
           
        }"

Comment: First: you only check if they are unequal, you need to check if they are smaller! Second, you increment them by one before calling the functions, which could make them too large, since indices start at 0. Third, you still have `GetValue(number)` which could be a too large index. Fourth, if you have a `WHERE` clause you could find less records than your `maxRows` which would make your check worthless again.

Comment: My first mistake was this: MaxRows2 = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; which should be MaxRows2 = ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count; now for some records it works. I'll try to edit as you said, thanks.

Comment: @Marco7757 Thanks Marco, I followed your hints and now my code is working. Now I check inc and inc2 if they are smaller than MaxRows and MaxRows2, then I start indices at -1. This is it and it works thanks